# Base class access specification vs class member access specification

Tags: c++

How is base class access specification different from member access specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base class access specification decides about base class' members access specification in *your* class. They provide a way to hide base class' members if you don't want them to appear publicly in your class. They doesn't affect visibility of members of your class though.

[C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html) explains this issue quite nicely.

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int A;
public:
    int B;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    // Derived1::A outside class is seen as protected
    // Derived1::B outside class is seen as public
};

class Derived2 : protected Base
{ 
    // Derived1::A outside class is seen as protected
    // Derived1::B outside class is seen as protected
};

class Derived3 : private Base
{ 
    // Derived1::A outside class is seen as private
    // Derived1::B outside class is seen as private
};
```